# Why it I used a global variable, and I try to put this element into an element of an array. Why am I getting an error?

Tags: c

I used a variable with the name INF.
And There is an error "The expression must have a constant value." at When declaring an array.
Why did I get an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 7;
int INF = 1000000;   

int w[7][7] = {
    {4,INF, INF, INF, INF,INF, 10},  
    {3,INF, INF, 18, INF, INF, INF},  
    {INF,6, INF, INF, INF,INF, INF},
    {INF,5, 15, INF, 2, 19, 5},
    {INF,INF, 12, 1, INF,INF, INF},
    {INF,INF, INF, INF, INF,INF, 10},
    {INF,INF, INF, 8, INF,INF, INF}
};
```

Comment: Because you cannot initialize a global variable like that. `#define INF 1000000`. Why are you not using `int w[NUM][NUM] = { ...`?

Comment: `#define`s should not have a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Is there any way to initialize an array using global variables without using macro variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `C` you cant use objects (a variable is an object) to initialize static storage objects (global variables and static local variables).

You have three options:

1. `#define  INF 1000000`
2. Initialize it in main (or any other function)

```
int INF = 1000000;   

int w[7][7];

void foo(void)
{
    memcpy(w, (int [7][7]){
    {4,INF, INF, INF, INF,INF, 10},  
    {3,INF, INF, 18, INF, INF, INF},  
    {INF,6, INF, INF, INF,INF, INF},
    {INF,5, 15, INF, 2, 19, 5},
    {INF,INF, 12, 1, INF,INF, INF},
    {INF,INF, INF, INF, INF,INF, 10},
    {INF,INF, INF, 8, INF,INF, INF}
    }, sizeof(w);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

3. If your compiler allows some function to be called before main start: gcc example

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) foo(void)
{
    memcpy(w, (int [7][7]){
    {4,INF, INF, INF, INF,INF, 10},  
    {3,INF, INF, 18, INF, INF, INF},  
    {INF,6, INF, INF, INF,INF, INF},
    {INF,5, 15, INF, 2, 19, 5},
    {INF,INF, 12, 1, INF,INF, INF},
    {INF,INF, INF, INF, INF,INF, 10},
    {INF,INF, INF, 8, INF,INF, INF}
    }, sizeof(w);
}
```

Comment: Re “In C you cant use objects… to initialize…”: This is incorrect for two reasons. One, you can use objects, as unary `&` and `sizeof` operands. Two, The C standard explicitly permits implementations to accept forms of constant expressions other than those it requires, so a C program may use the value of an object in implementations that support it. It is true that it is not portable but false that it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you. Your answers help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Compile-time constants in C can be created with enumerations (as in `enum { INF = 1000000 };`) or preprocessor definitions (as in `#define INF 1000000`). Compilers may accept other things (such as `static const int INF = 1000000;`) as compile-time constants, but the C standard does not require this, so it is not portable.

Using `1000000` for `INF`, suggesting infinity, is a bad practice. 1000000 will not act like infinity mathematically. For example, squaring it will not produce itself, and dividing it by large numbers will produce small numbers, unlike mathematical infinity. The C standard does not define integer overflow, so operations with 1000000 may produce undesired results. This includes assigning it to an `int` object in a C implementation with a 16-bit `int` type.

`INT_MAX` or negative numbers can be used as markers that an `int` is outside the domain of a particular application, if those values, respectively, are indeed outside the domain being used.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I didn't know the C standard didn't provide it...

Answer (score -1):

Make `INF` a constant expression using a macro:

```
#define INF 1000000
```

Some compilers (eg GCC and Clang) accept a `constexpr`-ish variable, without warning, even in pedantic mode, although it is not standard. However, you might like it to avoid macros:

```
const int INF = 1000000;
```

Comment: Duh... Thank you @bolov (my infant's alzheimer's must kick in when I get sleepy `:)`

Comment: @bolov Didn't for me I don't know why

Comment: it will not help. It has to be **constant expression** not **const variable**

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Yeah, both GCC and Clang threw me off. Let's add `constexpr` to C already.

Comment: @Acorn C++ and C are not the same. C does not have the idea of constructor needed for that. All initialized data must be known compile time. `const` objects have to to be known to the compiler compile time https://godbolt.org/z/3h43nn

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland `constexpr` is not about constructors but about compile time computation. In any language, including C and C++, initialization data for compile time constants needs to be known at compile time for obvious reasons...